# Android volley OutOfMemoryError on extremely large images

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory, android-volley

I'm using volley to load images into a `NetworkImageView` - but the images are uploaded by users, and there's no guarantee that they will be of reasonable size.

Right now I see `OutOfMemoryError` when fetching a large image such as this one: http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73751/world.topo.bathy.200407.3x21600x21600.C2.jpg

```
08-05 21:34:35.280    3435-3462/com.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-731
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:122)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.entityToBytes(BasicNetwork.java:256)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:129)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

The exception looks like it's happening inside of a thread so I don't really know how to catch this exception when it occurs.  Ideally I'd just show a placeholder and keep going, but right now my app just crashes instead.

I set up the image loader inside my `Application` object:

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, new LruBitmapCache(LruBitmapCache.getCacheSize(getApplicationContext())));
```

And I load the image using `setImageUrl` inside one of my `Activity` classes:

```
((NetworkImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageUrl(url.toString(), application.getImageLoader());
```

The standard suggestions of making sure the image cache doesn't grow too large don't apply here, I believe, because I see this crash even when loading just one large image into an otherwise empty cache.

Furthermore, looking into it a little bit, I don't believe this error is even in the ImageLoader code path, so tricks like scaling the bitmap etc. don't seem to apply here (even if I could find a way to get a handle on the `BitmapFactory.Options` object that volley is using).

Is there anything I can do to prevent this exception inside a volley thread from crashing my app?